# Popup window dismiss and open issue

Tags: android

I have 2 buttons that shows popup windows. I have coded for dismissing these popup windows when click outside.

My problem is ;

When 1st popup window is open, clicking 2nd button to open 2nd popup window, only closes the 1st popup window. To open second popup have to click on the button again.

Is there any way to avoid double clicking the button.

my code:

```
btn_a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popup_view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
            final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popup_view,200,110,true);
            popup.setFocusable(true);
            popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());
            popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            popup.showAsDropDown(btn_period,0,0);
        }   
    });


    btn_b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popup_view2 = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup2, null);
            final PopupWindow popup2 = new PopupWindow(popup_view2,200,110,true);
            popup2.setFocusable(true);
            popup2.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());  
            popup2.showAsDropDown(btn_shops,0,0);

        }   
    });
```

Comment: If your buttons are on the Activity layout, then clicking outside a popup will only cancel the popup, not triggering a click on the Activity layout's buttons

Answer (score 0):

You have to use these properties:

```
popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
popupWindow.setFocusable(false);
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);`
```

and when you click on second popup then close first popup by using this function:

```
if(popup_view.isShowing(){
  popup_view.dismiss();
}
```